# Laravel Eloquent model returns value even with a wrong condition

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I don't get the following problem :

1. `$user = App\User::where('id', 1)->first();` works
2. `$user = App\User::where('id', '1')->first();` works - same result
3. `$user = App\User::where('id', '1xxxx')->first();` works - same result
4. `$user = App\User::where('id', 'x1')->first();` doesn't work

I'm surprised by 2., more by 3. and even more by 4..
Any clue ?

Comment: I think, here is something hexadecimal should be the case. May be converting into the number which we are not expecting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `id` column is type of `int`, it is expecting an `int` value for compare and (int)'1xxxx' = 1 , so all these results are expected only.

using tinker

```
>>> App\User::where('id', '1xxxxx')->first();
=> App\User {#3118
     id: 1,
     name: "superadmin",
     email: "abajaj281@yahoo.com",
     created_at: "2019-01-11 19:06:23",
     updated_at: "2019-01-11 19:06:23",
   }
>>> App\User::find('1xxxxx');
=> App\User {#3123
     id: 1,
     name: "superadmin",
     email: "abajaj281@yahoo.com",
     created_at: "2019-01-11 19:06:23",
     updated_at: "2019-01-11 19:06:23",
   }
```

and

```
    >>> App\User::find('xxxxx1');
    => null
   Psy Shell v0.9.9 (PHP 7.2.10 — cli) by Justin Hileman
   >>> App\User::where('id', 'xxxxx1')->first();
   => null
   >>> App\User::where('id', 'x1')->first();
   => null
    >>>
   >>> App\User::find('x1');
   => null
    >>>
```

Comment: if I am not mistaken 'xxxx1' = 0 in where closure like (int)'xxxx1' = 0

Comment: @PeterEstiven check my answer, I have updated using tinker, I am getting null.

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu thanks. But, how can I be sure to have a response only if the condition is 1 or 2 or 3... I should have `null` if the condition is not an integer.

Comment: @PeterEstiven you will get null when ever you are retrieving the result using non integer, for `1xxx` situation, just before retrieving you can check using `is_int()`.

Answer (score 1):

It happens because, in background, it matches the `value` based on the column type.

Being the column an `int`, it **casts the value** into an `int` form, such as this

https://3v4l.org/JkU9H

Meaning all 3 points match `value 1`, while the last one matches 0 due to being unable to convert "x" into a `int`